# NDSolve or NDSolveValue for simple, 1D diffusion

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-element-method

Trying to solve a simple semi-infinite diffusion equation **numerically**.

At t=0, the value at z=0 rises from 0 to `cA02`, and diffuses in the positive x direction.

```
tfinal2 = 2*^5;
DAB2 = 3.4*^-9;
cA02 = 0.7;
zfinal2 = 100;

NDSolveValue[{
   D[cA[z, t], t] == DAB2 D[cA[z, t], {z, 2}],
   
   DirichletCondition[cA[z, 0] == 0, True],
   DirichletCondition[cA[z, t] == cA02, z == 0],
   DirichletCondition[cA[z, t] == 0, z >= zfinal2]
   },
  cA,
  {t, 0, tfinal2},
  {z, 0, zfinal2}
  ]
```

However, Mathematica has returned variations of nonsense, either all 0 or with portions dipping below 0 (impossible for diffusion). Tried tweaking the boundary condition expressions with no luck.

With some attempted reformulations of the boundary conditions I get `NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.`, with some I get none. Semi-infinite diffusion shouldn't be unstable to convection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get a warning (error message) from your code, don't you?

Comment: With some attempted reformulations of the boundary conditions I get `NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.`, with some I get none.  Semi-infinite diffusion shouldn't be unstable to convection.

Comment: The warning message was a hint (to me) how to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, I added your comment to the question. With especially the message name `femcscd`, it makes it easier for someone with the same problem to find this Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method of lines for the time integration and a smaller mesh seems to work, though the timescale seems short for the diffusion constant:

```
ClearAll[z, t];
tfinal2 = 2*^5;
DAB2 = 3.4*^-9;
cA02 = 0.7;
zfinal2 = 100;

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[cA[z, t], t] == DAB2 D[cA[z, t], {z, 2}],
    (*DirichletCondition[cA[z,0]==0,True];*)cA[z, 0] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[cA[z, t] == cA02, z == 0],
    DirichletCondition[cA[z, t] == 0, z == zfinal2]},
   cA, {t, 0, 100000 tfinal2}, {z, 0, zfinal2},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}},
     "TemporalVariable" -> t}];

Plot3D[sol[z, t], {t, 0, 100000 tfinal2}, {z, 0, zfinal2}, 
 PlotPoints -> {100, 25}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[The warning message in the OP's original code suggested that `NDSolve` was treating the problem as a 2D spatial (~steady-state) problem. That suggested explicitly separating the time integration.]